# two different html access in angular 6

Tags: html, css, angular, angular5, angular6

I have two different html files like,

1) home1.html

2) home2.html

**home1.html**

```js
ImgSrc : string = "https://brandmark.io/logo-rank/random/pepsi.png"
```

```html
<div>
<img [src]="ImgSrc" />
</div>
```

**home2.html**

```js
onMouseOver:void{

// change home1.html background image

}
```

```html
<div (mouseover)="onMouseOver()">
</div>
```

In home2.html file, if i mouseover i want to change the home1.html background image as "https://image.freepik.com/free-icon/apple-logo_318-40184.jpg" this.

Please help me how can I do this in angular 2 or 4 or 5 or 6?

Comment: How these two templates home1.html and home2.html connected? Do these components share some service? How are you sharing data between these two componets?(Assuming you have two components with these two templates)

Answer (score 0):

The answer would typically depend on how these 2 components are connected.

If they share a common parent, then you can go ahead and emit an event when `mouseOver` occurs on **html1** and then you could listen to that event in your parent and act accordingly.

However if they do not share a common parent or they have a common parent but it is higher in the component hierarchy, you could then write a shared service which would then inform **html2** that an event has occurred so act accordingly.

In order to provide code snippets, I would need to get how the components are connected and some basic code as to gain a little insight.

Comment: I am new to angular. So i don't know how to do.